# Principal Components - how to obtain linear transformations?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a list "xlsf" with 6 columns and 1200 rows for PCA analysis. The `PrincipalComponents[xlsf]` gives the following:

"The principal components of matrix are linear transformations of the original columns into uncorrelated columns arranged in order of decreasing variance"

How do I obtain the transformations performed on columns by *Mathematica*?

Comment: Use `SingularValueDecomposition`.

Comment: Or `KarhunenLoeveDecomposition`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PrincipalComponents` is based on [`SingularValueDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SingularValueDecomposition.html).  Below I'll show what it does:

This is some sample data from the docs:

```
data = {{13.2, 200, 58, 21.2}, {10, 263, 48, 44.5}, {8.1, 294, 80, 
    31}, {8.8, 190, 50, 19.5}, {9, 276, 91, 40.6}, {7.9, 204, 78, 
    38.7}, {3.3, 110, 77, 11.1}, {5.9, 238, 72, 15.8}, {15.4, 335, 
    80, 31.9}, {17.4, 211, 60, 25.8}};
```

Let's centre it first:

```
data2 = # - Mean[data] & /@ data;
```

Then compute the SVD of the centred data:

```
{u, s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[data2];
```

Now `Transpose[v]` is the rotation that `PrincipalComponents` applies to each row.

Comment: what happens if I do not center the data?

Comment: @denfromufa Do you understand the mathematics behind PCA?

Comment: now I understand that PCA can be obtained by doing SVD to centralized data: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca

Comment: I'm confused by your last statement. Using your variable names, the PCA-transformed data will then be obtained as `data2 . v`. Why do you refer to `Transpose[v]` as the rotation being applied?

Comment: In Mathematica's Implement, PrincipleCompoments seems a bit  from the SVD, use something like eigenSystems for Covariance matrix, because the SVD route gives the same result by DimensionReduce by LSA not the same with PrincipleCompoments